# INSERT INTO no funciona

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero agradecerles a todos por su tiempo de antemano.

Cuando trato de insertar una serie de datos en una tabla llamada "comentarios", no se da la respuesta afirmativa del mysqli_query que coloqué dentro del "if". He chequeado en detalle la base de datos para constatar que los nombres de los campos en los cuales quiero insertar las variables sean iguales a los que llamo en mi código SQL; también verifiqué que todas las variables posean un valor definido; y por último chequeé la sentencia SQL que hice para constatar que es sintácticamente correcta. Sin embargo, sigue apareciendo el error del "else"(específicamente el error "error2").

¿Ustedes ven cuál puede ser el problema en el código que les dejo acá abajo?

Código:

```
<?php

if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}

require_once("conexion.php");

$id_usuario = $_SESSION["id"];
$nombre = $_SESSION["user"];
$comentario = utf8_encode($_POST["comentario"]);
$fecha = utf8_decode(date("M jS\, Y (H:i a \U\T\C)" ,time()));
$articulo = utf8_encode($_POST["titulo"]);
$respuesta = false;
$identificadorUnico = mt_rand() . $fecha;
$img;

$query1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$id_usuario'";

if($resp1 = mysqli_query($conexion, $query1)){

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resp1);

    $img = "url('../" . $row["img"] . "')";

    $query2 = "INSERT INTO comentarios (id_usuario, nombre, img, comentario, fecha, articulo, respuesta, identificadorUnico) VALUES ('$id_usuario', '$nombre', '$img', '$comentario', '$fecha', '$articulo', '$respuesta', '$identificadorUnico')";

    if($resp2 = mysqli_query($conexion, $query2)){

        echo '
            <article class="ContenedorComentario">
                <h1 class="fechaDelComentario">' . $fecha . '</h1>
                <section style="background-image:' . $img . ';" class="imgUserComentario">
                    <article class="contenedorNombreDeUsuario">
                        <h1 class="nombreDeUsuarioQueComento">' 
                           . $nombre . 
                        '</h1>
                    </article>
                </section>
                <h1 class="comentario">
                    <div id="trianguloComentario"></div>
                        ' . $comentario . '
                </h1>
                <h1 class="responderComentario" onclick="responderComentario("' . $identificadorUnico . '")">Reply</h1>
         </article>
        ';
    }else{
        echo "error2";
    }
}else{
    echo "error1";
}

mysqli_close($conexion);

?>
```

Acá les dejo una screenshot de la tabla en la base de datos:

[image: Tabla "comentarios" en localhost]

Éste es el $query2 plasmándose en la página (petición de alguien que comentó el post):

[image]

Desde ya muchas gracias a todos!

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos un resultado de `echo $query2;` ? (agrégalo a la pregunta, no como comentario).

Comment: Lo acabo de hacer. Espero puedas ayudarme

Comment: Puede haber un error en el campo `img`, se está cerrando antes con la comilla simple después de `url(`.

Comment: Era eso! Muchisimas gracias!

Comment: Este código puede sufrir ataques de [inyección de SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL) y de [inyección de código (XSS)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) y su uso en producción no es recomendable. Deberías sanear todas las entradas que vengan del usuario y además utilizar consultas preparadas/parametrizadas.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario y tu tiempo. Si, lo se. Solo quería saber que anduviese, mas luego agregaría los parámetros de seguridad necesarios a la entrada de comentarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elimina las comillas simples o cámbialas, en la variable img:

```
$img = "url(../" . $row["img"] . ")";

$query2 = "INSERT INTO comentarios (id_usuario, nombre, img, comentario, fecha, articulo, respuesta, identificadorUnico) VALUES ('$id_usuario', '$nombre', '$img', '$comentario', '$fecha', '$articulo', '$respuesta', '$identificadorUnico')";
```

Comment: Si, eso fue lo que hice. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!